# Create JSON and format double values

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

Is there any way to set a format of double values when I create JSON with NSJSONSerialization?

For example:

```
    let dict :Dictionary<String,NSNumber> = ["key1" : 75.01, "key2" : 80.93, "key3" : 79.07, "key4" : 79.10 ]
    let JSONData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    let JSONText = NSString(data: JSONData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    NSLog("JSON string = \(JSONText!)")
```

I get the following output:

> JSON string = {
>     "key1" : 75.01000000000001,
>     "key2" : 80.93000000000001,
>     "key4" : 79.09999999999999,
>     "key3" : 79.06999999999999
>   }

I would like to avoid these 000001, 0999999, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Float" instead of "NSNumber":

```
let dict: Dictionary<String,Float> = ["key1" : 75.01, "key2" : 80.93, "key3" : 79.07, "key4" : 79.10 ]
```

Result:

> JSON string = {
>     "key1" : 75.01,
>     "key4" : 79.1,
>     "key2" : 80.93,
>     "key3" : 79.07
>   }

Comment: Unfortunately I do not create JSON myself, I receive it from AFNetworking.

Comment: Why are you telling me now that you don't create the JSON yourself, since your question is *entirely* about creating the JSON? Please clarify the situation and be precise. For now, this comment is in contradiction with the question. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry. I just wanted to provide several values to illustrate the problem. I suppose that it is obvoius that data could be different.

Comment: Btw, your answer gave me a tip. I created another dictionary with Floats and copied a structure and values from the source dictionary to the new one. It works good for my task. Thank you.

Comment: Well yes, my answer still aplies indeed. You're welcome. :)